# Static dictionary containing delegates to instance methods

Tags: c#, delegates

I have this method with a huge switch statement like this:

```
public bool ExecuteCommand(string command, string args)
{
    bool result = false;
    switch (command)
    {
        case "command1": result = Method1(args); break;
        case "command2": result = Method2(args); break;
        // etc.
    }
    return result;
}
private bool Method1(string args) {...}
```

Now I thought about replacing this with a dictionary of `Func<>` delegates so that I can eliminate the switch statement:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<string, bool>> _commands = new ...;
public MyClass()
{
    _commands.Add("command1", Method1);
    // etc:
}
public bool ExecuteCommand(string command, string args)
{
    return _commands[command](args);
}
```

The problem I see with this, is that a new Dictionary is instantiated and populated with each new instance of MyClass.

Is it possible to somehow make that Dictionary (containing delegates to instance methods) a static member, which would be initialized only once, in the static constructor?

E.g. something like this (does not work):

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<string, bool>> _commands = new ...;
static MyClass()
{
    // the following line will result in a compiler error:
    // error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
    // method, or property 'MyClass.Method1(string, string)'
    _commands.Add("command1", MyClass.Method1);
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work, what's the error? Maybe if you lazy-initialize in a static getter, it it works? That's how I go it usually, for singleton, etc.

Comment: @ewernli: updated the question with the compiler error. (note: I need to call instance methods, not static methods).

Comment: The error you are receiving is referencing the attempt to add `MyClass.Method1` as a `Func<string, bool>` in your dictionary. Not the static set up of the Dictionary itself. Is the `Method1` method off `MyClass` a static method? The error you are receiving indicates it's not and the compiler expects it to be.

Comment: Have you tried just `_commands.Add("command1", Method1);` ?

Comment: Are the instances of the same type, base type, or interface?

Comment: y not make the class singleton?

Comment: Rob: gives the same error.  Clayton: everything is in the same class.   zenwalker: the above code is simplified. I need multiple instances of MyClass (each with state), so I cannot make it a singleton.

Comment: If it's all the same class you can follow a set up like Jon Skeet's answer or just simply add that as a parameter to your func signature. `Dictionary<string, Func<InstanceClass, string, bool>> _commands` then use that to populate a delegate method. `_commands.Add("command1", (instance, s) => instance.Method1(s));`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You *can* initialize it in the static constructor - but you'll need to create instances of `MyClass`, which may not be what you want, because I assume you want the command to execute "in the context of" the instance which `Execute` has been called on.

Alternatively, you can populate the dictionary with delegates which *take* an instance of `MyClass` as well, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    static Dictionary<string, Func<MyClass, string, bool>> commands
        = new Dictionary<string, Func<MyClass, string, bool>>
    {
        { "Foo", (@this, x) => @this.Foo(x) },
        { "Bar", (@this, y) => @this.Bar(y) }
    };

    public bool Execute(string command, string value)
    {
        return commands[command](this, value);
    }

    public bool Foo(string x)
    {
        return x.Length > 3;
    }

    public bool Bar(string x)
    {
        return x == "";
    }
}
```

In theory I believe it should be doable without the lambda expression by creating an "open delegate", but it would need a bit more work using reflection. If you don't mind the ugliness and *tiny* performance penalty of the extra indirection, I think this approach should work quite well.

Comment: Yes, I want the command to be executed on the same instance where Execute() was called - so your alternative solution seems to be what I need. Thanks.

Comment: This is an old thread but I would like to know the impact of the static dictionary with delegates on garbage Collection. My guess is since it is static dictionary, it would eventually get promoted to generation 2 and might just stay there and not get garbage collected. Your thoughts please Jon

Comment: @AlwaysAProgrammer: I don't see why delegates are particularly relevant to that. Yes, the delegates will exist forever... but that's the intention in this case...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jon